# NodeJS: Uploading plain text to s3 via Knox and I get statusCode = 505?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, coffeescript

I have the following code, where message is a JSON String. I am trying to upload this to s3 with the md5 of message as the destination filename. I am getting a '505' statusCode. I am new to NodeJS and not sure what I am doing wrong here?

```
knoxInitParams =
    'key': awsKey
    'secret': awsPrivateKey
    'bucket': bucket

client = knox.createClient knoxInitParams   

buff = new Buffer message
reqHeader = 
    'Content-Length': buff.length
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    'x-amz-acl': 'private'

req = client.put '/tmp/xxx.txt', reqHeader
req.on 'response', (res) ->
    console.log res.statusCode
    console.log res.headers
    if res.statusCode is 200
        console.log res.url
req.on 'error', (err) ->
    console.error "S3 Error: ", err
req.end buff
```

Edit:
Changed the destination to hardcode it, as a reply below pointed out that was causing the issue. However, I am now getting a 403 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Make sure your date/time are correct.  `ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That fixed it ... Should have thought about this :(

Answer (score 5):

Quick note, I ran into this issue, too, but my error was that I had a space in my filename.

`var req = client.put('/tmp/x xx.txt', reqHeader);`

I wrapped the filename, like this

`var req = client.put(encodeURIComponent('/tmp/x xx.txt'))`

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your bug is here:

```
req = client.put destination.toLowerCase + '.txt', reqHeader
```

You probably want to invoke `destination.toLowerCase`:

```
req = client.put destination.toLowerCase() + '.txt', reqHeader
```

On the other hand, I think it's wholly unnecessary -- it will be lowercase already.

On a side note, you may want to look into unit testing -- it's a great way of catching these kinds of bugs! If I were you, I would add a function, say `getFileName`:

```
getFileName = (contents) ->
  crypto.createHash('md5').update(contents).digest('hex') + '.txt'
```

Now you can easily test this function with nodeunit, mocha, jasmine or any of the other great test utilities, and make sure that it always returns what you expect -- and if not, help you notice immediately where the error is.

I can also heartily recommend node's debugger, which also helps you catch these bugs.

Comment: Ah, I am new to CoffeeScript and made a mistake there. I fixed that and now I am using a constant 'tmp/xxx.txt' as file name. However, now I am getting a 403 (Forbidden). I am a 100% that my key + secret is correct, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for the tips, I should def. be unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your exact code with my own S3 account, it works fine:

```
$ coffee test
200
{ 'x-amz-id-2': 'f5C32nQHlE0WI8jtNFEZykRFAdrM8ZdBzgeAxc23bnJ2Ti4bYKmcY3pX/KpEzyZg',
  'x-amz-request-id': 'B41AACFF85661C2E',
  date: 'Tue, 01 May 2012 23:15:39 GMT',
  etag: '"44b25eb6d36a88713b7260d8db15b24b"',
  'content-length': '0',
  server: 'AmazonS3' }
```

Check your ID/key/bucket, and date/time as @skrewler suggests.

Comment: Thanks yea, I tried the suggestion above and that fixed it. I wish Amazon would launch their own official node.js sdk

Comment: @Saad, it would be nice, though in this case knox has done pretty well!

Comment: Definitely. I do miss the more detailed error messages. Like with the Amazon PHP SDK, you actually get the time offset message. With Knox, you pretty much just get the statusCode (unless I am missing something?)

Comment: @Saad You can listen for data events from the response
  `req.on 'response', (res) -> 
     res.on 'data', (data) -> console.log data.toString()`